# Filter and retrieve data from a c# Dictionary using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have `ListA` and `ListA` has `ListB` 
I need to retrieve all the *keys* of `ListA` which has a Particular *Key* in `ListB`

**Eg:**

if I give `123` as *key* of *listB* I should get `<ABC,UVW>`

if I give `246` as *Key* of `ListB` I should get `<ABC>`

**ListA[0]**

```
Key: ABC (double)
Value:
Desc: XYZ (string)
ListB[0]
    Key:123
    Val:321
ListB[1]
    Key: 246
    Val: 642
```

**ListA[1]**

```
Key: UVW
Value:
Desc: XYZ
ListB[0]
    Key:123 (string)
    Val:321 (double)
ListB[1]
    Key: 343
    Val: 100
```

Select All Key of ListA Where ListB.Key= 123

Expressions tried

```
ListA.Values.Where(b => b.ListB.Key==123).Select(a=>a.Key)
```

> Error : error CS1061: 'Dictionary' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Key' and no accessible extension method 'Key'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
ListA.Where(p => p.ListB.Contains(123)).Select(p=> p.ListA.ToList()
```

> error CS1061: 'KeyValuePair' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ListB' and no accessible extension method
>   ListB accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Below ids the class defn

```
class cListA

{
private Dictionary<string, double> ListB = new Dictionary<string, double>();

private string Desc;

public Dictionary<string, double> ListBvar
    {
        get
        {
            return ListB
        }
    }


    public string sDesc
    {
        get
        {
            return Desc
        }
    }
}

private Dictionary <string, cListA> ListA= new Dictionary <string, cListA>();
```

Comment: The errors do not seem to reflect the code. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Actual code is same with different variable names

Comment: That might be, but the error does not reflect your code

Comment: `ListA.Values.Where(b => b.ListB.Key==123).Select(a=>a.Key)` has no no mention of a `Value`, the error and the code doesn't make sense, the compiler doesn't make up words and errors. Please double check your code and errors

Comment: @TheGeneral I pasted the wrong error mesage. I have updated the error message

Comment: Also your second example is wrong too

Comment: @SMD - Can you please post class definitions for the lists and also provide the initial data in valid C# code?

Comment: @Enigmativity Below is the class definition

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Update the question dont put code in the comments

Comment: @SMD - Your code doesn't compile. Is this your real code? Also, please provide the sample data in valid C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it the answer was pretty simple.

```
ListA.Values.Where(p=> 
       p.ListB.Values.Contains(123)).Select(a=>a.Key).ToList().
```

Comment: This is good. Could you please update your question with the sample data in valid C# code and then show in this answer how it gets the right result for you. We strive for good quality questions and answers on Stack Overflow.